# Need to add html input values which are part of a mysqli array

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, mysqli

I am an extreme newbie when it comes to coding but here it goes anyway. I have a table which has the first two columns populated from MySQL database and each row gets a text box for user input. This is then written back to the database. This works fine, i need to get the total from the user input of each text box as they are inputting it and subtract that from another text box earlier on the page. I need to get the sum of the budgetamount input field.

Here is my table code:

```
    <span id="sum">0</span>
    <?php
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT envelopename, envelopebudget FROM envelopes");
        echo "<table border='1' id='table_new_paycheck'>
        <tr>
        <th>Envelope</th>
        <th>Budget</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
        echo "<input type='hidden' value='$row[envelopename]' name='envelopename[]'/>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['envelopename'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['envelopebudget'] . "</td>";
        ?><td><input type="text" name="budgetamount[]" class="textboxone"></td><?php;
        echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        mysqli_close($con);
    ?><br>
```

Here is the jquery script i tried but it does not work:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
$(document).ready(function(){

    //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
    //handler to trigger sum event
    $(".textboxone").each(function() {

        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSum();
        });
    });

});

function calculateSum() {

    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".textboxone").each(function() {

        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }

    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

I was trying to go with jquery thinking this would give me instant reponse as they typed in the values for each textbox but i am not sure how to go about this. this is an example of what i kind of want but i could not adapt it to work with my array. [Here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/sum-html-textbox-values-using-jquery-javascript/) is an example of what i am looking for somewhat. It covers the adding portion.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Soemthing like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Newtt/Lseg900t/1/

Comment: Yes but there will be an undefined number of values so i cant give specific variables to add. The only variable is whatever they input into the undetermined number of text boxes.

Comment: You can just repeat the number of TRs

Comment: But since the textbox in part of an array it has no specific variable name unless i can pass the budgetamount[] on to the jquery which it have tried and it won't handle it.

Comment: Can I see what you've tried so far? Use JsFiddle if needed or add the code here.

Comment: i have updated the original question with the jquery code i tried to adapt to my circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

Applying the keyup handler directly to the returned jQuery object seem to work well.

I've made an update to the Fiddle that Newtt made that I think will accomplish what you're looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lseg900t/2/

Note the second parameter "10" when using `parseInt()`:

`sum += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);`

this ensures that you get a base-10 integer back. If you don't explicitly tell it to use base-10, if a user entered "012" this would be interpreted in Octal (base-8) and have a value of 10 in base-10, which likely isn't what you're looking for.

**EDIT**: Also note, I'm not doing any of the NaN checking that you've done.

**EDIT**: it seems parseInt now defaults to base 10, unless otherwise specified, even still better to be explicit and provide the parameter.

I've adjusted the Fiddle, further, allowing for the other user input that you've mentioned. See the update here http://jsfiddle.net/Lseg900t/3/

Comment: this still doesn't work with my scenario. not sure why except maybe it has something to do with the array but i don't know. i don't think it is even calling the script or making it to the script at all. i have tried putting document.writes statements in the jquery and they never appear so i am not sure.

Comment: Well, having the script execute is definitely the first step :)

One can use console.log() as well, and the output ends up in the developer console, or in firebug's console, if you have that installed (if you don't and you're doing javascript development, you should really check it out.

Comment: Firebug will also show you any syntax/parse errors encountered in the javascript.